# Should I free the string returned by cStringUsingEncoding?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If I'm calling `[NSString cStringUsingEncoding:]`, should I `free()` it once I'm done using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and the documentation says so quite clearly:

> The returned C string is guaranteed to be valid only until either the receiver is freed, or until the current autorelease pool is emptied, whichever occurs first. You should copy the C string or use `getCString:maxLength:encoding:` if it needs to store the C string beyond this time.

Comment: What does it mean by "until the receiver is freed"? I'm not sure I understand the term "receiver" here. Does it talk about the current instance?

Comment: receiver is the object the message was sent to - so in this case the MSString instance

Answer (score 0):

I think cStringUsingEncoding is allocating memory for the converted string to specified encoding So if you are not using an auto release pool, this memory is never freed.